# Sequelize decimal data save with 2 decimal points

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I'm using sequlize ORM for my Node.js project. Below code is one column in a table.

```
   itemPrice: {
      type: DataTypes.DECIMAL,
      allowNull: false,
      field: 'itemPrice'
    },
```

It is generate the MYSQL DB column as decimal(10,0). It means it cannot save decimal points data. When I'm going to save 12.26, it is save 12. How to create column with saving 2 decimal points.

I tried below code also. It doesn't execute and occurred an error.

```
   itemPrice: {
      type: DataTypes.DECIMAL(10,2),
      allowNull: false,
      field: 'itemPrice'
    },
```

Please show me a direction to do this...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`type: DataTypes.DECIMAL(10,2),` should work. Once a table is created via `sync`, it will not be altered even though you have changed your data model definition.

You can use `{force: true}` in your `sync` function. **Remember that this will drop your table and recreate it.**

```
sequelize.sync({ force: true })
  .then(()
```

Comment: Thanks... Now Decimal(10,2) worked... I dont know what happened in earlier... Anyway, good to know, if I use { force :  true } will drop the table and re-create.... :)

Comment: That, or `{alter: true}`

Comment: A bit late to the party, but it's interesting to look into Umzug (https://github.com/sequelize/umzug) , which allows you to specify migrations.